# How to make sure that you stay relevant while working at a dead end job?

Tags: job-change, skills

I am working at a job which has no potential for growth and due to uncertainty I may lose my job in future. Job is very niche and may not have overlapping skills with other jobs that may be available at that time when I am fired or lose my job. Considering I am in my early 30s I may not be preferred for entry level jobs for other roles that I may apply for by gaining those skills. So how do I prepare myself for this uncertainty?

Or simply put how does one get over age based discrimination that is present everywhere when applying for entry level roles?

I don't have inclination towards programming or software development. I am looking more towards finance and management in general.

Comment: Is there perhaps neighboring fields where if you spend your free time acquiring some knowledge about, that knowledge overlaps well with the one you have ? Thus making a nice portfolio of "skills" ?

Comment: This is a little to less information to give a good answer, but anyway. I started a new (sort of) entry level job in my early 30's so it is possible.

Comment: I don't think age discrimination will be too strong for people in their 30's. I mean you don't give the domain you work in, but you should be fine getting a job of some level in your 30's. In terms of how you "get over it", well that's a psychological factor - essentially you just ignore the idea of this bias, go to interviews and present yourself as best you can and don't worry about potential discrimination. Confidence and knowledge will ultimately trump bias trends, just need to pursue all the opportunities you can.

Comment: The heading and the last line in the body are asking for two different things

Comment: "`I am working at a job which has no potential for growth and due to uncertainty I may lose my job in future`" - why are you still there? And would you stay forever if you don't lose your job? I don't really understand; are you happy there, or not? Are you already looking or have you no interest in leaving?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I live in 3rd world country. People liking their jobs is rare sight. Got to pay the bills somehow.

Comment: There is a Dilbert cartoon that says "don't expect work to be fun. If it was, the company would make you pay to come to the office" :-)

Comment: I think that you should be looking for a new job ***now***.

Comment: don't wait to get fired. read read read read read and learn everything you can about your job. ask questions to people that work with you. do everything you can at your current job. you will not even notice when you are able to look for another job. and one thing that I learned over the time, MARKETING! you NEED TO KNOW HOW TO SELL YOURSELF to the company. you know not so much? it doesn't matter. get a suit, a good cv and start to hunt for new jobs right now.

Answer (score 3):

We have had a few similar questions : niche or obsolete skills, how can I find a new job, in a new field?

The answer is generally to prepare yourself to look attractive to employers in the new field.

Try to volunteer for some Open Source projects in your new field of interest, or at least crate a portfolio, put an app on GitHub, read lots of books, take lots of training courses (*), especially if they offer a qualification, or at least an acknowledgement that you completed them.

(*) [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses) offers hundreds of free courses from top universities world wide.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be:

- don't wait to get fired, but start right now with your job search and the preparation to said jobsearch
- learn something you'd like to do in the future. How about https://fast.ai for example?
- start making something yourself. Either work on open source projects or - what I as a hiring team lead find even more impressive - start a side project. Get inspired by indiehackers for example.
- do something that I call 'career due diligence' (would love to help in this field - just shoot me a note) to make sure that you don't end up on a dead-end in your next gig again.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to break into any field is to start doing it for charity.  I've done this myself.  Due to employment laws being as they are, any employer worth his salt is looking for experience.  Experience is actually more important than education in most instances.

Find a charity that needs help with it's finances, or management and do some work for them.

It may require a temporary sacrifice of all free time, and even reducing your sleep for a while, but think of it as an investment in your future.